# Cmd prompt windows compiling

Tags: c, windows, winapi, cmd, command-prompt

For my WINAPI projects, I am using [atom IDE](https://atom.io/) with c programming, I could compile my code from cmd prompt without a problem until I have started using `.rc` files. but now that I am using rc files before compiling my program I need to run these commands on the cmd prompt.

```
gcc -c jake.c
gcc -o jake jake.o -mwindows
windres -o jakerc.o jakerc.rc
gcc -o jake jake.o jakerc.o -mwindows
```

typing them all again and again to see if my program works correctly each time is really tedious. (Also please do not tell me to use IDEs like DEV c++ or Visual Studio because I don't like them as much as I like atom.)

so I have came up with this solution. I have made an extra file called `compile.c` which inside it looks like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  system("C:\\Users\\hashtag\\Desktop\\rawsock\\kokul gcc -c jake.c");
  system("C:\\Users\\hashtag\\Desktop\\rawsock\\kokul gcc -o jake jake.o -mwindows");
  system("C:\\Users\\hashtag\\Desktop\\rawsock\\kokul windres -o jakerc.o jakerc.rc");
  system("C:\\Users\\hashtag\\Desktop\\rawsock\\kokul gcc -o jake jake.o jakerc.o -mwindows");
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this program I get this error:

```
'C:\\Users\\hashtag\\Desktop\\rawsock\\kokul' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I get rid of this error, and how do I automatically compile my files when I run `compile.exe`?

Comment: use a parameterized batchfile

Comment: can you show it just to make sure? @SebastianL

Comment: I see two choices: Either make a `.bat` script file which does all this for you. Or learn how to use `make`, `nmake` or similar tools.

Comment: Also, the second command (`gcc -o jake jake.o -mwindows`) makes no sense, since you then overwrite the executable when linking with the resource.

Comment: If you like Atom, give [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) a run. It's the same editor, basically, but also provides [complete C++ programming support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp). You can configure the editor to use any compiler. Also comes with debugger support (like GDB or LLDB). All configurable through text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in my comment, i'd recommend using a batchfile and not a compiled c program for this.

Example:

```
@ECHO off
SET workingDirectory=%~dp0
SET fileName=%1
echo using %workingDirectory% as working directory
gcc -c %fileName%.c
gcc -o %fileName% %fileName%.o -mwindows
windres -o %fileName%rc.o %fileName%rc.rc
gcc -o %fileName% %fileName%.o %fileName%rc.o -mwindows
```

you could run your desiered commands with `nameofthebatchfile.bat jake`

Answer (score 1):

As long as kokul is a directory the command line

```
C:\\Users\\hashtag\\Desktop\\rawsock\\kokul gcc -c jake.c
```

Doesn't make sense.
You can combine multiple commands. If you want to change into the directory kokul and start the compile this will work

```
CD C:\\Users\\hashtag\\Desktop\\rawsock\\kokul & gcc -c jake.c
```

But anyhow writing a batch file is much easier:

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two lines

```
windres -o jakerc.o jakerc.rc
gcc -o jake jake.c jakerc.o -mwindows
```

Save them to file "mj.bat", then run form command prompt by typing "mj".

When your project grows beyond two or thre files, you should use makefile
[GCC and Make Compiling, Linking and Building C/C++ Applications](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)

Check also `atom-shell-commands` or `run-command` package for Atom. You can run this directly form editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with command-line tools, this task just seems to cry out for a Makefile. Not only will `make` automate the necessary actions, it will try to work out from the file timestamps which actions actually need to be carried out. If you haven't changed a C source file, for example, you don't need to recompile it. The effectiveness of `make`, or similar, will increase enormously as your applications get larger and have more complicated dependencies between components.

You can do some of this stuff with simple batch files but, ideally, the batch file needs to stop when any of the steps encounters an error. There's no point carrying on a long build process that is doomed to fail, and finding the relevant error message in pages of irrelevant output can be a chore. This is another thing that `make` just does right.

It can take a while to get on top of Makefiles, with their arcane syntax. However, the effort will be rewarded many times over in the longer term.